# Field of fractions and integral closure of $\mathbb{Q} + x\mathbb{R}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R=\mathbb{Q}+ x\mathbb{R}[x]$.

What is its field of fractions and the integral closure in its field of fractions?

Comment: Do you have any ideas? First of all, do you understand the notation?

Comment: See the paper cited [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1871672/242) for a comprehensive analysis of rings of this type.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): first edit your post to show your own work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will give a brief sketch, perhaps you can fill in the details: The field of fractions is $\mathbb R(x)$.

The integral closure of $R$ is $K+x\mathbb R[x]$, where $K=\overline{\mathbb Q}\cap\mathbb R$ is the field of real algebraic numbers. Indeed, clearly all elements of $K+x\mathbb R[x]$ are in the integral closure. Conversely, suppose $f\in\mathbb R(x)$ is in the integral closure of $R$. In fact, since $\mathbb R[x]$ is integrally closed, we must have $f\in\mathbb R[x]$. But now $f$ satisfies some monic polynomial equation
$$f^n+a_{n-1}f^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0=0$$
where $a_i\in R$. Substituting $x=0$ (i.e., applying the surjection $ev_0\colon\mathbb R[x]\to\mathbb R$) gives:
$$f(0)^n+a_{n-1}(0)f(0)^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0(0)=0.$$
By definition all $a_i(0)\in\mathbb Q$, so $f(0)\in K$, as desired.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the [standards for the site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Instead of answering it (which encourages low-quality questions), why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) regarding quality standards.